# Can DocC interactive tutorials be hosted?

Tags: swift, swift5.7, docc, xcode14.3

I'm exporting and hosting DocC documentation successfully on GitHub pages for my Swift framework yet the interactive tutorials I've written don't seem to be accessible.

I've tried multiple different urls `/documentation/myframework/tutorials/`, `/tutorials/` etc.. but they don't seem to be anywhere on the static hosted site. Do I need to do something special to get those hosted?

In the Xcode Developer Documentation window, the tutorial table of contents shows up as a sibling to the rest of my documentation, rather than a child, I'm thinking that may have something to do with it but my folder structure seems correct.